# Uncaught TypeError: binding.destroy is not a function in ExtJs 5

Tags: javascript, extjs, mixins, extjs5, bindable

I am using `Ext.util.StoreHolder` mixin in my `extjs 5.1` view.I found problem with `Ext.destroy()` method which throws error while destroying view having bindable mixin **Ext.util.StoreHolder**. I can not destroy that view, it giving me error

> Uncaught TypeError: binding.destroy is not a function
>
> at Ext.define.privates.removeBindings

My view is using mixin:

```
mixins: {
    bindable: 'Ext.util.StoreHolder'
},
```

Is there any problem with Ext.util.StoreHolder mixin? Why can't I destroy that view?

Edit -> , please find my code

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.ux.CustomPagingBar', {
    extend: 'Ext.toolbar.Toolbar',
    alias : 'widget.custompagingbar',
    mixins: {
        bindable: 'Ext.util.StoreHolder'
    }
});
```

[image: Error stack]

Find Fiddle here [Grid with Paging bar destroy issue](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/obr)

Comment: Why are you using StoreHolder explicitly in your view? Can you share some code?

Comment: @Yellen I have updated my question with my code..I am using `StoreHolder` for paging bar which I use for grid views...Initially I was using `Ext.util.Bindable` in ExtJs 4.2 but after up gradation to ExtJs 5.1, I replace Ext.util.Bindable with Ext.util.StoreHolder

Comment: How is your onDestroy like?

Comment: Ext.destroy(gridview)

Comment: Question - does gridview have the paging bar?

Comment: I have added snapshot of error stack in questions...yes Grid view has that  paging bar..

Comment: Can you show your bindings?

Comment: @Yellen...`var pagingBar = me.queryById('paging-bar');
        if(pagingBar){
         pagingBar.bindStore(Store);
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ext JS 5, `Ext.mixin.Bindable has a new config--"bind"--` which allows bind descriptors to be defined on components.

In my component's "bind" method is overwriting this, and so the binding cleanup process is trying to destroy a binding, but doesn't have the proper configuration for it.

Commenting "bind" method prevent the destroy issue.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are unbinding the store when destroy is called on the view.

I think this should work.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.ux.CustomPagingBar' ,{
   extend: 'Ext.toolbar.Toolbar',
   alias : 'widget.custompagingbar',
   mixins: {
      bindable: 'Ext.util.StoreHolder'
  },

  // other code

  onDestroy: function(){
      var me = this;
        me.bindStore(null);
        // some other custom code if you want
        me.callParent();
    }


});

    // me.bindStore(null); this will unbind the store from the view before it is destroyed
```

Comment: You've onDestroy defined inside your CustomPagingBar?

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-destroy

Comment: no I don't have any onDestroy inside CustomPagingBar..I try your updated answer but still getting same problem `binding.destroy is not a function`

Comment: Can you test in Chrome and enable pause on exception and check which binding is causing it?

Comment: @Yellen...I try your answer to add onDestroy inside CustomPaginBar...still having same issue....`binding.destroy is not a function`. After debugging more it show me location where the error get thrown..`removeBindings() method from Ext.mixin.Bindable`

Comment: @AbhijitMuke - I cannot say much unless I see much more of the code.

Comment: @Yellen....I think you can help me...can we discuss more in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80061/uncaught-typeerror-binding-destroy-is-not-a-function-in-extjs-5

Comment: @AbhijitMuke - You should post it in Sencha forum as well.

Comment: @Yellen I got exact same problem because of a store binding: `items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'infocard',
                        bind: {
                            store: '{infoStore}'
                        },`. I've replaced `onDestroy` method you gave on the panel which I'm using the  `bind` config and placed it as listener but both way did not work. Still says: `binding.destroy() property not defined`. How can I over come?

Comment: I'm developing sencha's admindashboard and error raises during closing view on `Tab`. Probably view's `destroy` method and binding's are messing up.

Comment: @NuriEngin which extjs version are you using?

Comment: @Yellen I'm using 6.5.3